# Unity : is it possible to configure the scene for trigger colliders to only work with one layer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collider

Unity already manages the collisions and triggers well but I would like to know if I can optimise triggers to only react to a layer ?

Currently if I have many different objects with colliders in a scene I need to do :

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
    if (other.gameObject.layer == myLayer) {
        // do stuff here
    }
}
```

But this means that the collisions where calculated with ***ALL*** of the colliders witch does not seem efficient.

If I want a trigger to react to the player and to the player only, is there a way to tell it to ignore all of the other layers to avoid unnecessary computing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the Collision Matrix as described in the manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).

Answer (score 1):

- Add a new layer mask (or just use the one you already have)
- Uncheck all of the layers it can collide with except the "Player" layer
- Change the game object's layer to the new modified layer
- Now that object can only collide with the player, and only get triggered by the player (provided one of them has a rigid body component)

Answer (score 1):

Add a new layer and assign it to the gameobject which has the collider component that is unwanted to collide target gameobject. And go to project settings -> physics. You will see a layer collision matrix and you can manage which layer intersects which one.